# pass an array to dialog menu

Tags: bash, unix, dialog

i have a problem with my shell script.

My script ask the user which Partition the want to backup.

This wouldn't be a problem with

```
var=$(df -hT | awk '{print $7}')
```

But how i can pass my array "var" to dialog?

```
dialog --menu "Please choose a mounted Partition" 15 55 5
```

Comment: why the negativ?
please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numbers as tags:

```
var=$(df -hT | awk '{print v++,$7}')
dialog --menu "Please choose a mounted Partition" 15 55 5 $var
```

Comment: this doesn't work here. zsh 5.0.2 dialog,  1.1-20120706. it worked if I switched to bash (+1 for the answer)..

Answer (score 2):

`dialog --menu` expects at least 6 parameters. if you pass the $var to it, still one is missing.

one way you could go is:

```
var=$(df -hT | awk '{a[$7]=$7}END{for(i in a)printf i" "a[i]" "}')
```

then:

```
dialog --menu "Please...." 15 55 5 $(echo $var)
```