# Array to strings of index value pairs

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to create a string of index and value pairs. This is to be used in `dialog` menu.

```sh
declare -r -a arr=(
  piano
  table
  chair
)

dialog \
--backtitle "Launcher" \
--title "App" \
--ok-label 'Select' \
--cancel-label "Back" \
--menu "Select an application" \
$dialog_height $dialog_width 4 \
"1" "piano" \
"2" "table" \
"3" "chair"
```

So I'm looking to have the:

```sh
"1" "piano" \
"2" "table" \
"3" "chair"
```

generated automatically from array.

There's a similar question [pass an array to dialog menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177067/pass-an-array-to-dialog-menu) I tried what's there I couldn't get it to work for me.

Comment: Show how you tried to use the code from the other question. If it worked for them, it should work for you, too.

Comment: Note that the solution there expects each value to be on a separate line when piping to `awk`. Did you do that when piping your array values?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"` will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To auto-generate the tags `1`, `2`, `3` in front of every array entry, use

```
items=(piano table chair)
taggedItems=()
for ((i=1; i<="${#items[@]}"; ++i)); do
  taggedItems+=("$i" "${items[i-1]}")
done
# then use "${taggedItems[@]}"
```

Opposed to your linked `awk` solution, this works with arbitrary items that may contain spaces, special symbols like `*` and even linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
declare -a arr=(
  ''
  piano
  table
  chair
)
unset 'arr[0]'
declare -ar arr

# Remove the echo below once ready for the fun.
echo dialog \
--backtitle "Launcher" \
--title "App" \
--ok-label 'Select' \
--cancel-label "Back" \
--menu "Select an application" \
$dialog_height $dialog_width 4 \
$(for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "$i" "${arr[i]}"; done)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OPTIONS=(1 "table"
         2 "piano"
         3 "......")

dialog \
--backtitle "Launcher" \
--title "App" \
--ok-label 'Select' \
--cancel-label "Back" \
--menu "Select an application" \
$dialog_height $dialog_width 4 \
"${OPTIONS[@]}" \
 2>&1 >/dev/tty
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, using simple array:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -r -a arr=(
  piano
  table
  chair
)

options=$(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | awk '{print v++,$arr}')

dialog \
  --backtitle "Test" \
  --title "Test" \
  --menu "Test" \
  0 0 4 \
  $options \
  2>&1 >/dev/tty
```

Or with associative array:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -r -A arr=(
  piano
  table
  chair
)

options=$(printf '%s\n' "${!arr[@]}" | awk '{print v++,$arr}')

dialog \
  --backtitle "Test" \
  --title "Test" \
  --menu "Test" \
  0 0 4 \
  $options \
  2>&1 >/dev/tty
```

To start menu numbers at 1:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -r -a arr=(
  piano
  table
  chair
)

options=$(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | awk -v v=1 '{print v++,$arr}')

dialog \
  --backtitle "Test" \
  --title "Test" \
  --menu "Test" \
  0 0 4 \
  $options \
  2>&1 >/dev/tty
```

To use both key and value of associative array in menu:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -r -A arr=(
  [piano]=piano
  [table]=mesa
  [chair]=cadeira
)

options=$(printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]} " "${arr[@]}")

dialog \
  --backtitle "Test" \
  --title "Test" \
  --menu "Test" \
  0 0 4 \
  $options \
  2>&1 >/dev/tty
```

Comment: What is the point of the associative array here?

Comment: @LéaGris well, if someone has an associative array and want to display it in the menu with numbers he can use that code.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer works both with normal and associative arrays of entries, using numerical index or associative key as menu key:

**Normal array of menu entries, using numerical index as menu key:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=(
  piano
  table
  chair
)

options=()

for k in "${!arr[@]}"; do
  options+=( "$k" "${arr[$k]}" )
done

dialog \
  --backtitle "Test" \
  --title "Test" \
  --menu "Test" \
  0 0 4 \
  "${options[@]}" \
  >/dev/tty 2>&1
```

**Full example with associative array:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A assoc=(
  [p]=piano
  [t]=table
  [c]=chair
)

options=()

for k in "${!assoc[@]}"; do
  options+=("$k" "${assoc[$k]}")
done

choice="$(
  dialog \
    --backtitle "Test" \
    --title "Test" \
    --menu "Test" \
    0 0 4 \
    "${options[@]}" \
    2>&1 >/dev/tty
)"

clear
case $choice in
  t)
    printf %s\\n "Let's set the table."
    ;;
  p)
    printf %s\\n "Let's play piano."
    ;;
  c)
    printf %s\\n "Let's sit dow."
    ;;
  *)
    printf %s\\n "Let's decide later."
    ;;
esac
```